# Windows 7 not mounting volume on restart

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, mount

On my system Windows 7 is not mounting one of my partitions on restart.
I manually got to mount it which is really annoying.
It is a HFS+ partition which needs a special driver (MacDrive) to be loaded, so this might be the reason.

Using `MOUNTVOL P: VOLUMENAME` is working from cmd, but when putting it into Task Scheduler O just get "Device not ready" when trying to access it.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

It was a problem with the partition itself, after rebooting my Task Scheduler entry is working. Looks like MacDrive doesn't like me mounting and unmounting several times.

If you got other ideas for this then the task scheduler, feel free to answer.

Comment: There should be an option when loading the driver to 'make available to windows upon startup' or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the partition itself, after rebooting my Task Scheduler entry is working. Looks like MacDrive doesn't like me mounting and unmounting several times.

If you got other ideas for this then the task scheduler, feel free to answer.